# CMake include/source paths valid configuration

Tags: c++, cmake

I have following C++ project structure:

```
Project
├───inc
├───src
└───tests
    └───googletest
```

The CMakeLists inside root folder has the following contents:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(Project)
add_subdirectory(tests)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(Project_run main.cpp)
```

And the CMakeLists inside tests folder:

```
project(Project_Tests)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_subdirectory(googletest)
include_directories(${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${gtest_SOURCE_DIR})
include_directories(${gmock_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${gmock_SOURCE_DIR})

add_executable(Google_Tests_run test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Google_Tests_run gtest gtest_main gmock)
```

It compiles fine. Now I would like to have class headers inside `inc` folder and sources inside `src` folder. Should I use new CMake file inside `src` folder? Also the project files should be available inside googletests library.

Comment: It's up to you to choose whether you want another CMake file inside the `src` folder. From what you've shown here, it doesn't seem like it would matter if you made a new CMake file in `src`, or listed your headers/sources in the top-level CMake file... Did you try it? Did you encounter errors when trying it?

Comment: In the root CMake file I added ``include_directories(inc)`` but how to do it with ``src`` directory? The same way doesn't work.

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are trying to do. Please explain in your question post *where* you want these class headers/sources added. Do you want them to be compiled as part of the `Project_run` executable target? Do you want them to be a *separate* library? Also, what do you mean by "*the project files should be available inside googletests library*"?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to have headers in ``inc`` directory and sources in ``src`` directory. Both should belong to Project_run target.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Also, what do you mean by "the project files should be available inside googletests library"?

Comment: I should be able to include files from ``inc`` inside ``Project_Tests`` project.

Comment: Do you intend to test the functionality in these class sources using `Google_Tests_run`? Because this would suggest you probably want to **link** them to that executable as well, not only include their headers. Please edit your question post to *explain your intent*.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following to your `CMakeLists.txt` file in your "tests" folder:

```
target_include_directories(Google_Tests_run PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/inc)
```

Try to add the above line **BELOW** your `target_link_libraries(Google_Tests_run...)` . That should work.

For info: `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` expands to your project root-folder.

*Note:* Try to always use `target_include_directories` over `include_directories`.